# Inserted rows into a PostgreSQL database only visible in JSF after Glassfish restart

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

When I insert new data into a database table, in some cases the changes are only visible in the browser when restarting the server.
Does anyone know a good solution for this problem? 
Maybe there's some kind of cache for the queries Glassfish is using, but I don't know how to disable it. I am using Glassfish 3.1.

Comment: JSF is not a persistence framework. It's just a web MVC framework. I removed the JSF tag. What persistence API/framework are you using? Hibernate, JPA or plain JDBC? How are you managing transactions? Manually or by EJBs?

Comment: OK Sorry I am very new in this thing...
I'm using plain JDBC, and managing by EJBs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you're committing the transaction?